# Audio file compression identification

Tags: unpacking, file-format

I've been working on reversing file formats from the game of star wars episode 1: the phantom menace.

I have managed to extract the audio files from the .lab file in which they were contained. I cannot however play the audio files.

The files are provided at the end of the question.

I managed to find some of the decompressed files in the game's cache (which do play) and so I have a selection of audio files in both compressed and uncompressed form.

The compression ratio is about 66%; i.e. the compressed file is 1/3 of the size of the uncompressed size.

This is an example of the uncompressed and compressed form of the data. (From BDm8906.wav and BDM8906.wv)

The first 32 bytes of the uncompressed file (Magic is riff) BDm8906.wav

```
52 49 46 46 DA 77 00 00 57 41 56 45 66 6D 74 20
10 00 00 00 01 00 01 00 22 56 00 00 44 AC 00 00
```

The first 32 bytes of the compressed file (Magic is INDYWV) BDM8906.wv

```
49 4E 44 59 57 56 22 56 00 00 10 00 00 00 01 00 
00 00 F1 2B 00 00 00 00 00 00 B6 77 00 00 00 00
```

From looking a few of the compressed files I have found that:

The first 16 bytes are always the same.
The next 4 bytes are the size of the compressed file.
The next 6 bytes are always zero.

Here's a more detailed look at the hexdump of the compressed file:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDpGy.jpg

(SE will not let me upload it).

From byte 25 (start counting at 0) to the end of the file is always different. The number of bytes from here to the end of the file is the size of the compressed file indicated earlier.

Attempts to decompress:

1) Thorough googleing. One other guy on the lucas forums and on the xentax forums attempts to decompress it without success. It is not wavepack.

2) Trying common compression algorithms on the uncompressed files. Compress, lzma, gzip do not even come close to the compression ratio reported.

3) Binwalk on the binary:

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             Microsoft executable, portable (PE)
715764        0xAEBF4         YAFFS filesystem
721564        0xB029C         YAFFS filesystem
746196        0xB62D4         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x64, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 16777216 bytes
```

When I run binwalk on windows I get that it includes DMC (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Markov_compression)

4) Dissembling the Binary and trying to find the location of the decompression code - this is quite difficult

A sample (two files, one encrypted one unencrypted) can be found here:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jvljza0v76mvl56/AAC41MenYP57dVHgAXY-DkSsa?dl=0

How can I figure out what it is using?

Thanks

Edit
According to reaper, decompressed file:

22.05 sample rate
16 bits per sample
15323 samples
694 ms

whatever the game does has decoded it into 15323 16 bit integers

Comment: First thing i'd do is run the game with ProcMon. Check where it reads from the .lab file and where it writes the .wav file. Check the stack at these calls to find out which functions from the binary call it. The whole thing is probably quite similar to my answer to [this](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9168/reversing-encryption-by-analysing-executable/9171#9171).

Comment: INDYWV appears to be a proprietary audio file format used by LucasArts. The game Star Wars: X-Wing Alliance also uses INDYWV files. Best bet is to do what @GuntramBlohm said above.

Comment: I don't know if this is the answer you're looking for, but you can use an application called SCRUMM Revisited to decompress the SW TPM music  (and sound effect) files to .WAV format http://jsg.id.au/scumm/scummrev/index.html the music files are in the \music directory with a .IMC extension, and the .LAB files contain many sound effects.

Comment: By the way, the main theme is called "SQSTALK2.IMC"